# How to convert java or class file to exe file

Tags: java, swing

I have been created a java app using swing and I want to convert to an exe file how to do it.

```
public Performance() {
    f = new JFrame("Ticket Booking");
    f1 = new JFrame("Payment Details");
    f2 = new JFrame("Payment Successfull");
    l1 = new JLabel("Movies :");
    l2 = new JLabel("Timing :");
    l3 = new JLabel("Class:");
    l4 = new JLabel();
    l5 = new JLabel();
    l6 = new JLabel("No of Person:");
    l11 = new JLabel("Movies :");
    l22 = new JLabel();
    l33 = new JLabel("Timing :");
    l44 = new JLabel();
    l55 = new JLabel("Class:");
    l66 = new JLabel();
    l77 = new JLabel("No of Person:");
    l88 = new JLabel();
    l99 = new JLabel("Amount:");
    l00 = new JLabel();
    lsuccess = new JLabel("          Thank u For booking Ticket...");
    c1 = new JComboBox(s1);
    c2 = new JComboBox(s2);
    r1 = new JRadioButton("10:00pm");
    r2 = new JRadioButton("1:00pm");
    r3 = new JRadioButton("4:30pm");
    buttongroup = new ButtonGroup();
    b1 = new JButton("Submit");
    b11 = new JButton("Pay Bill");
    b22 = new JButton("Edit");
    t1 = new JTextField(10);
}
```

Comment: When posting code, be sure to post *relevant* code... how is your code relevant to your specific problem?

Comment: This is my part of my code

Comment: What you want to do is theoretically possible but incredibly complicated and klugy.

Comment: *"How to convert java or class file to exe file"*  Why?  Java has [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to launch rich client apps. JWS works on Windows, OS X and *nix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert (actually, package) .class files into .jar files, you use the [Jar tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html). You can then generate a .exe file from the .jar using tools like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), JSmooth or several other packages (search the web for "jar exe").